# Create multiple target for multiproject in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

My main scala project has a structure as follows. It contains two sub-projects.

```
├── build.sbt
├── project1
│   ├── src
│   ├── build.sbt
│   ├── conf
├── project2
│   ├── src
│   ├── build.sbt
│   ├── conf
├── target
```

My requirement is to have 3 targets in main project's build.sbt. I have create fat jar so I am using assembly plugin to build the projects.

```
Target1: this builds both project1 and project2
Target2: this builds project1
Target3: this builds project3
```

My main project's build.sbt looks as follows:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  version := "1.0",
  scalaVersion := "2.10.4")

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).aggregate(jar1,jar2)   

lazy val jar1 = project.in(file("project1"))
                  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
                  .settings(
                    name := "project1",
                    assemblyJarName in assembly := "project1.jar",
                    test in assembly := {},

                   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(...),                
)

lazy val jar2 = project.in(file("project2"))
                  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
                  .settings(
                    name := "project2",
                    assemblyJarName in assembly := "project2.jar",
                    test in assembly := {},

                   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(...),

                )
```

With this build.sbt, when I use `sbt assembly`, It acts as `target1`. I am not sure how to create `target2(builds project1)` and `target3(builds project2)`.

Any suggestion how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why in the folders layout you have shown there's only one `target` folder in the aggregate project? I think by default in multiproject builds SBT creates a separate `target` folder under each subproject...

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it suffice to start sbt and in the sbt shell issue the commands

```
project project1
sbt assembly
```

This should just build project1 (in the project1/target folder).